# image problem with dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

i'm trying to create a newsletter in a single html file, which will be loaded into outlook express and sent out as a mail.

i have like a few images embedded onto the html file but 2 of them cant be loaded for preview in design mode. there is no problem for the rest of the images. those images that cant be loaded has the grey color icon.

the directory for the images are the same. i have copied and pasted the absolute directory for the images that cant load and it doesnt work.
the images loads fine when executed from the html file that was uploaded to the webserver.

edit:
it only loads fine in firefox, and not ie!

i need to get the newsletter out tomorrow, any assistance here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are the images? You will probably be best to just host the entire page on a server, and only email the HTML. Make sure the HTML references the server version of the images though.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a transparent PNG. If you are using an old version of IE, you are out of luck for the HTML email. Try using another type of image (8-bit PNG, PNG with no alpha values, JPEG, GIF). Open the image in your editor and save it as an 8-bit PNG, for example. An 8-bit PNG can only have binary transparency. You may have to redesign the page/email.